# What is the best alternative to HTTP_ORIGIN/HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
if (strpos($origin, "mydomain.com") > 0)
    header('"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://' . $origin . '"');
```

I want any of our subdomains (*.mydomain.com) to be able to use these pages but prevent access by external entities.  However, neither HTTP_ORIGIN or HTTP_REFERER work (haven't used them in a while but they used to).  I get the error

> Undefined index: HTTP_ORIGIN

and siimilarly for HTTP_REFERER.  Also, I understand that both of these are not secure and that the external URL can be spoofed.

Note:  I know some browsers don't support these but that is not relevant here because there is no browser involved.  I am using curl locally (on remote machines) to call the page directly on the server (Apache2 with PHP5.6).

So what is the best alternative to capture the calling script's domain?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that your check also matches `xmydomain.com.evil.com`, and the extraneous double quotes in the header argument, the code makes sense. You just have to check if HTTP_ORIGIN actually exists in $_SERVER. [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) can do that.

Comment: You have a good point, but I can improve that check. As far as the isset, I already know that HTTP_ORIGIN does not exist and that is what I need an alternative to.

Comment: There is no alternative. If the client doesn't tell you, you don't know. That's all there is to it. You can, of course, simply reject the request if the header is missing.

Comment: But it must be passing a header because I do get CORS errors. Or have I misunderstood something here?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) && preg_match('!^http(s)?://([a-z0-9\-]+\.)?example\.com$!is', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']))
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
}
```

I'm using this and you can try it. Please remember, if the browser don't sent origin header it will pass the argument.

or using htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://([a-z0-9\-]+\.)?example\.com$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
Header merge Vary Origin
```